# How to rbind dataframes in a for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I am  trying to create a dataframe combined of many dataframes created by a for loop. I know for loop is not recommended but since I feel more confortable using it.
I am looping through a list of elements in keyword_page of a dataframe df.

What I did works fine but my method is create all the dataframes with the for loop and only combine them when the for loop is over.

I would like to have a method that will add the dataframe to the stack of the previous dataframes created in the for loop, so that I can delete the dataframe right away after the rbind within the for loop and not at the end of it.

```
i=1

for (page in as.character(df$website)){

  keywordA <- data.frame(matrix(page))
  keywordB <- data.frame(matrix("REVIEW"))
  keywordC <- data.frame(df$keyword_page[i])

  assign(paste0('table_page', i), data.frame(keywordA, keywordB, keywordC))

i <- i +1

}
table_page_all <- rbindlist(mget(ls(pattern = "^table_page\\d+")))
colnames(table_page_all) <- c("KEYWORD A", "KEYWORD B", "KEYWORD C")
rm(list = (ls(pattern = "^table_page\\d+")))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Instead of creating many data.frames in the global environment you should just create a list of data.frames. This way you won't need to delete them one by one, rather you can delete the whole list at once. This should be something like `l <- lapply(as.character(df$website), function(x) <your function>) ; table_page_all <- rbindlist(l) ; rm(l)`. Also, I really think you should review your function as it doesn't seem to do anything useful that yo couldn't just do in one go and without creating all of these data.frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
i=1
table_page_all  <- data.frame()
for (page in as.character(df$website)){

  keywordA <- data.frame(matrix(page))
  keywordB <- data.frame(matrix("REVIEW"))
  keywordC <- data.frame(df$keyword_page[i])


   i <- i +1
   table_page_all  <- rbind(table_page_all, data.frame(keywordA, keywordB, keywordC))
}

colnames(table_page_all) <- c("KEYWORD A", "KEYWORD B", "KEYWORD C")
```

Comment: Just posted a similar answer, but created the first line outside the loop, way more beautiful with just rbinding to an empty `data.frame`.

Comment: This is called "growing objects within a loop" - not very good practice in R

Comment: Totally agree. But in the question It was stated to use a loop, so I obligues! Thanks

Comment: Thank you ! Works fabulous. What is the main reason why one should avoid using for loops ?

Comment: @ML_Enthousiast It is not that for loops should be avoided, per se, it is that the specific code in the for loop in this answer is an approach that is widely discouraged because is will scale very, very, very poorly. Iteratively adding onto objects in a for loop is *extremely* inefficient. Generally, experienced folks writing good answers on this site won't write answers like this at all.